# How to do Real-time output in Navigation bar?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photography

I have been using photoshop a while now. And love watching tutorial and doing them too. In **PLEARN** (photoshop youtube tutorial), a **real-time output** of the web-camera is shown in the **navigation panel**. How do they do it? Is there some extensions or plug-in? OR is that just customized by the programmer or company itself?

Thanks in Advance ...
@royalgcorps

Answer (score 1):

That picture in picture of the presenter has **nothing** to do with Photoshop. It is a video overlay on the video of the tutorial. It's **entirely** unrelated to the actual tutorial video in construction.

[image]

This is **not** done with Photoshop in *any* way.

Answer (score 0):

Navigator panel is company itself made.
The Navigator offers an easy and direct method of scrolling and zooming in and out of the image window. The panel window contains a small preview of image.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably done in post.

So you record everything and then drop the "real-time output" on top using your favorite video editing software.

Of course you do not have to do it in post if you have the right video recording software, but you should never make a tutorial live anyway. That is just asking for disaster.